# WPF How to disable DropShadowEffect

Tags: wpf

What's the best way to disable a DropShadowEffect, for example if you know you are running in a remote session?

I can think of setting the color to transparent, the blur radius to 0, or the opacity to zero, but not sure if there's any difference in these choices, or if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Style triggers + RenderCapability Tiers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henryh/archive/2006/08/23/719568.aspx) is what you need.  There are slightly more friendly ways return the render tier capabilities but the general idea is there.  When using terminal services, or there's no render capability for hardware effects, you can remove the effect with a style trigger.

```
<Style>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Perf:RenderCapabilityWrapper.Tier" Value="0">
      <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    </Trigger> 
    <Trigger Property="Perf:RenderCapabilityWrapper.Tier" Value="1">
      <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource performanceShadow}"/>
    </Trigger> 
    <Trigger Property="Perf:RenderCapabilityWrapper.Tier" Value="2">
      <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource qualityShadow}"/>
    </Trigger> 
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Great example, thanks. I take it that hardware capabilities would be detected on a GoToMyPC session, right?

Comment: @Dean Sorry, I don't have any personal experience with GoToMyPC and RenderTierCapability, should be quite easy to test though!

Comment: I meant to say _would not_ be detected on GoToMyPC. But yes, easy to test.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of disabling the DropShadowEffect you could style the control to not even use the effect in the first place.

Comment: I need to disable it when running in a remote session only. We have some users that use Citrix, and others that use it directly on their PCs.

Comment: So you could have 2 separate styles. One that gets used for desktop users, and one that gets used for Citrix\RDP users.
You would have to then either need some flag on your view models, use theming or use StyleSelectors to make sure that you select the correct style for the context that the application is running in.

Comment: Trying to get it simpler than restyling. If the transparent color basically removes the entire effect from any graphics engine processing, then that would be fine. Wouldn't isEnabled be nice?!?!

Comment: I can't think of any reason that setting the Color to transparent or playing with the BlurRadius wouldn't work.
You could also try just setting control.Effect = null which removes the effect completely.